# ADF activity does not return proper error codes

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

when an activity failed because of unauthorized
it is returning below error message with bad request code - not 401 error.
is there any better way we can capture error messages in ADF

```
Operation on target copy_api_to_file failed: 
  Failure happened on 'Source' side.
  ErrorCode=UserErrorHttpStatusCodeIndicatingFailure,
  'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
  Message=The HttpStatusCode 401 indicates failure,
  xxxx,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

Comment: Hi @Kasun, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We can see that the error message contain `Message=The HttpStatusCode 401 indicates failure.` The HTTP status 401 response code indicates that Unauthorized because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Since this is Azure data factory product issue, we recommend that you can raise a new ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/). Product team will check it and reply you.

In addition, we could Monitor and Alert Data Factory by using Azure Monitor, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#configure-diagnostic-settings-and-workspace) for more details.